# Explicit type of class expression

Tags: typescript, types

If I have the following type and function

```
interface Mapper {
  mapper: (number) => number
}

function withNumberAdded(num: number) {
  return class implements Mapper {
    mapper = (n: number) => num + n
  }
}
```

What is the exact type returned by `withNumberAdded`? Atom tells me its `typeof Anonymous class`, but then if I do this

```
const IMPL = withNumberAdded(88)
console.log(new IMPL().mapper(33))
```

This compiles. But if I intentionally put a typo and write `new IMPL().mappr(33)`, compilation fails with

> Property 'mappr' does not exist on type '(Anonymous class)'. Did you
>   mean 'mapper'?

So it seems that Typescript knows much more than `(Anonymous class)` about this type :)

If I want to explicitly specify the type, how to do this? Doing

```
function withNumberAdded(num: number): Mapper
```

doesn't work (because it's an instance type I guess).
What should I put after last `:` then?

Comment: `typeof Mapper`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, that fails, because `typeof` works on values, not types.

Comment: Ah, because it's an interface; for an interface you can use the constructor interface `new() => Mapper`. See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Do you want to post this as an answer so I could accept it? :)

Comment: FWIW, the exact type is not `new() => Mapper` but `new() => C`, where C is the anonymous class (which there is no way to name from outside `withNumberAdded`).  But `C` is assignable to `Mapper`, so `new() => C` is assigned to `new() => Mapper`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return a class which does not match the interface, it only matches an *instance* of the class.

In JavaScript a "class" has two sides, a static side (constructor and static methods/variables) and an instance side (not static methods/variables).

You can create interfaces for both sides, in your example the static side interface would only have the constructor as you dont have any static variables or methods:

```
interface MapperConstructor {
   new(): Mapper;
}
```

now you can use this constructor interface as return value:

```
function withNumberAdded(num: number): MapperConstructor { 
    // .. 
}
```

See also: [TypeScript documentation about interfaces(class types)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#class-types)

Comment: What also works as per comment above is I could just specify return type as `new() => Mapper` without declaring a constructor interface.

Comment: true, there are multiple ways to do this in typescript.